# Flutter Firestore pagination using StreamBuilder for Chat app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, pagination, flutter-layout

I know how to make pagination with **FutureBuilder**,

however when I'm using **StreamBuilder** things gets tricky and complicated.

I tried to increase the **document limit** upon **scrolling** but this would **restart the stream** which will cause **more quote** "Reading the data twice, triple and so on".

Please help.

Comment: not use any loop while you using stream builder and also avoid to use set state in stream builder

Comment: Can you please provide the code for pagination using stream ? or you can also take a look to this post where there is an example of [Flutter Firestore pagination using streambuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59191492/flutter-firestore-pagination-using-streambuilder)