# Firebase: How to get only n records at a time instead of whole record firebase real time database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a Flutter application where I need to get 10 records at a time from Firebase Realtime Database. Then on pressing a button, get the next 10 records.
Currently, the code I am using is returning all the records

```
final snapshot = (await ref.child('user').get());
```

Is there a way to get the first 10 records and after button press get the next 10 records?

Comment: Did you see the Firebase documentation on [filtering and limiting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)? You'll also want to look at some of the previous [questions on Firebase Realtime Database pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-realtime-database%5d%20pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then on pressing a button, get the next 10 records.

What you are looking for is called pagination. The key to solving this problem is to [limit the results](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) that are coming from the Realtime Database, and load the next n, on request. Here is a concrete example:

- [Pagination in Flutter with Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54464899/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-realtime-database)

Comment: Thanks. I was not unaware of term pagination so it was hard to find solution.